# Save MySQL results in 2D array - php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to fetch the result of a query to my database. I have no problems doing so when the resultset is just 1 row, but when it's multiple rows I only get the first one.

Here is my db:

```
-----keys-------------------
|  id  |  key_nbr |  date  |
----------------------------
|  42  |  abc123  |  xxxx  |
|  49  |  789xyz  |  wxyz  |
----------------------------
```

My function:

```
function get_key_info($mysqli) {
   if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'], $_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['login_string'])) {
       $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
       if ($stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, key_nbr, date FROM keys WHERE id=$user_id")){
           $row = $stmt->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
           return $row;
       }
   }
   return null;
}
```

Output when doing `print_r($row);` is only the first row:

`Array ( [id] => 42 [key_nbr] => abc123 [date] => xxxx)` How to make it print all rows?

Comment: [`$row = $stmt->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) instead of `$row = $stmt->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Comment: Sidenote: [`keys`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) is a MySQL reserved keyword. Wrap it in backticks `\`` or use another name for it. Having used [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) which you're most probably not doing, would have signaled the error. Always use error reporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check for total number of rows before fetching the data, if it's not zero then execute the loop and fetch all records.

```
function get_key_info($mysqli) {
   if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'], $_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['login_string'])) {
       $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
       if ($stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, key_nbr, date FROM keys WHERE id=$user_id")){
           if($stmt->num_rows != 0) {
               $row = array();
               while($r = $stmt->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                   $row[] = $r;
               } 
               return $row;
           }
       }
   }
   return null;
}
```